# scp via jumphost but network channel prohibited?

Tags: ssh, scp

I wanna scp to a host in intranet via a jumphost,

OpenSSH 7.3+ allows `-oJumpHost` parameter, but companies' jump host says

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

Is there other way?

I can not use `nc` either, it's prohibited.

I don't want to type `scp` twice.

Comment: Most probably not. Talk with your company IT guys to allow this feature.

Comment: Or a hostname based whitelisting.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 It's company wide policy, I cant easily change that.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Comment: @AlastairIrvine thanks but in my case I knew it's prohibited and i can not change that config. I need a workaround.